# Fire event comment.create with live-stream facebook plugin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-analytics, facebook-comments

The event **comment.create** fired when the user adds a comment **(fb:comments)** and the event **comment.remove** fired when the user removes a comment **(fb:comments)**
view : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

If I want to detect the same events in **(fb:live-stream)** http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/
may I use **comment.create** and **comment.remove** or 
something else like event **stream.publish** and **stream.remove**

Answer (score 0):

Neither https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ nor http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/ indicate there's any public event you can subscribe to for the Live Stream plugin.  If you think this is valuable to have, log a bug/enhancement request with Facebook and post the link to the bug report here.  Thanks  :)